# Is there a convenient way to reference a DOM element in Svelte components?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I am used to libs/frameworks like React or Angular which both have convenient ways to access actual DOM elements that belong to logical components. React has the `createRef` utility and Angular has among other things the template variables in combination with eg. `@ViewChild`.

Those references not only make it easy to access the DOM without querying the elements explicitly every time , they also stay up to date with the DOM so that they always hold reference to the current element. I just started with Svelte for my pet project but although I went through Svelte's documentation and google a lot, I didn't find anything similar in concept & usage. I suppose it might have something to do with the Svelte's runtime-less concept, but still don't know why there wouldn't be such a utility.

So the question is, is there a similar utility in Svelte?

Comment: @skyboyer i think you pasted wrong URL. I'm guessing it should be this one: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you guys!

Comment: I think `use:action` is what you're after https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Based on the example found at https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this (thanks to @skyboyer), you can use `bind:this` ([try in REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a50ee99d3f774860b7fb568e0e6dd208?version=3.12.1)):

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let myInput;

    onMount(() => {
        myInput.value = 'Hello world!';
    });
</script>

<input type="text" bind:this={myInput}/>
```

You can also use `use:action`, as seen at https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action and suggested by @collardeau ([try in REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b686c734b93549878c34d905af4e4662?version=3.12.1)):

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let myInput;

    function MyInput (node) {
        myInput = node;
        myInput.value = 'Hello world!';
    }
</script>

<input type="text" use:MyInput/>
```

Comment: @SuperUberDuper it's not wrong, but by using Svelte's bindings (especially when you don't need to access DOM element, just value, e.g., `bind:value={myInputValue}`) you get two-way value changes, without having to implement them yourself. Compiler will take care of keeping them up-to-date for you.

Comment: Both are pretty slick ;)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore.