# How do I scroll to the last item in an {#each} block in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

In svelte, I'm currently templating out an array of `messages` like this:

```
{#each messages as message, i}
    {@const isLast = i === messages.length - 1}
    
    <div class="card" class:active={isLast}>
        {message}
    </div>

{/each}
```

I then have a function where I can append a new item to the array

```js
function addNextWord(){
    messages = [...messages, words[index]];
}
```

When I do so, I'd like to scroll the very last item into view (using something like [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)).

But how can I get a reference to *just* the last item in the loop?

#### [Demo in Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d491ee731ce6474bad301888c1bff911?version=4.1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action).

```js
const initialCount = messages.length;
const scroll = node => {
    if (messages.length > initialCount)
        node.scrollIntoView()
}
```

```html
<div class="card" use:scroll ...
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a6b622df6cee4946b047305bcc586d2d?version=4.1.2)

In the vast majority of cases actions are just better than `bind:this`.

Comment: Ahh... this is much simpler.  So the action is fired *"when an element is created"* so almost like a lifecycle method available from the parent.

Comment: Actions can also return an object with a `destroy` function, so yes, pretty much lifecycle access for elements.

Comment: Slightly different scope, but if the each block child was a svelte component, is there a different event to tap into without just having to wrapping in a div to allow for using actions? [Example in REPL with component in #each](https://svelte.dev/repl/cc15a95d2b7944dda035372bf98032fe?version=4.1.2)

Comment: Unfortunately there is not, so sometimes I do just add a wrapper. For some actions the wrapper can be set to `display: contents`, so it does not interfere with layout as much. (The limitation is to be expected though, components can theoretically not contain any elements at all.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't *conditionally* set a binding on an element, so the two strategies would be to set a `bind:this` on the parent container or [on an array of child items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75221982/1366033) and then pick what one you want from there.

Using the [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-this) directive allows you to [reference a DOM element from a variable in svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58362558/1366033).

Once you have a reference to the parent you can use [`Element.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild) to [get the last child from a parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72750452/1366033).

Finally, you'll have to wait for a [`tick`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#tick) for the data changes to propagate to the DOM before selecting the last item.

Put all together, it should look something like this:

```html
<script>
    import { tick } from 'svelte';
    
    let messages = ["Hello", "World"];
    let listContainer;
    
    async function addNextWord(){
        messages = [...messages, words[index]];
        await tick();
        listContainer.lastChild.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth"});
    }
</script>

<div bind:this={listContainer}>
    {#each messages as message, i}
        {@const isLast = i === messages.length - 1}
        
        <div class="card" class:active={isLast}>
            {message}
        </div>
    
    {/each}
</div>
```

#### [Demo in Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d2a989e224594ce5863e33ec82a383a0?version=4.1.2)

**See Also**: [How to scroll to the last item when adding a new one on a list?](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/voyovj/)